# Objective-C: full list of file paths to images and videos in the device

Tags: objective-c

I need to retrive the full list (as comma-separated NSString) of file paths to images and videos stored in an iPhone.

I wrote the following code, currently it gets only images. Can you show me how to improve that code to get also video? Thank you

Please also check if there is something wrong: I have the impression to get less photo then the ones actually stored in the device.

```
#import <Photos/Photos.h>

-(NSString*)listItems{

    PHFetchResult *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:nil];

    // NSLog(@"Total: %d",(int)result.count);

    NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[result count]];
    
    for (PHAsset *asset in result) {
        [asset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:[PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions new] completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput *contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info) {
                NSURL *imageURL = contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL;
            [images addObject : imageURL.absoluteString];
        }];
    }

    NSMutableString * listFiles = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    for (NSObject * obj in images)
    {
        [listFiles appendString:[obj description]];
        [listFiles appendString:@","];
    }
    return listFiles;
}

@end
```

Comment: There will be photos that your app has no right to access. And you don't ask for any videos, so you are not going to get any.

Comment: I know that my code is incomplete and does not make any requests for videos: because of my lack of experience with Objective-C, I ask for help here.