# Codename One "out of memory" when using Object-C native interface (HEIC to JPEG conversion)

Tags: codenameone

Since I'm implementing a custom gallery for Android and iOS, I have to access directly to the gallery files stored in the `FileSystemStorage` through native interfaces.

The basic idea is to retrieve the file list through a native interface, and then make a cross-platform GUI in Codename One. This works on Android, I had to make the thumbs generation *(in the Codename One side, not in the native interface side)* as fast as possible and the overall result is quite acceptable.

On iOS, I have an additional issue, that is the HEIC image file format, that needs to be converted in JPEG to become usable in Codename One. Basically, I get the file list through [the code in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64132167/1277576) *(I'm waiting for an answer...)*, then I have to convert each HEIC file to a temporary JPEG file, **but my HEICtoJPEG native interface makes the app crashing after few images** with an "out of memory" Xcode message...

I suspect that the problematic code is the following, maybe the `UIImage* image` and/or the `NSData* mediaData` are never released:

```
#import "myapp_utilities_HEICtoJPEGNativeImpl.h"

@implementation myapp_utilities_HEICtoJPEGNativeImpl

-(NSData*)heicToJpeg:(NSData*)param{
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:param];
    NSData* mediaData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.9);
    return mediaData;
}

-(BOOL)isSupported{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

This is the Java native interface:

```
import com.codename1.system.NativeInterface;

/**
 * @deprecated
 */
public interface HEICtoJPEGNative extends NativeInterface {
        
    public byte[] heicToJpeg(byte[] heicInput);
}
```

and this the Java public API:

```
import com.codename1.io.FileSystemStorage;
import com.codename1.io.Util;
import com.codename1.system.NativeLookup;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class HEICtoJPEG {
    private static HEICtoJPEGNative nativeInterface = NativeLookup.create(HEICtoJPEGNative.class);
    
    /**
     * Public API to convert an HEIC file to a new JPEG file (placed in /heic)
     * @param heicFile in the FileSystemStorage
     * @return a new file (with unique name)
     */
    public static String convertToJPEG(String heicFile) throws IOException {
        if (nativeInterface != null && nativeInterface.isSupported()) {
            
            // It ensures that the directory exists.
            FileSystemStorage fss = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
            String heicDir = fss.getAppHomePath() + "/heic";
            if (!fss.isDirectory(heicDir)) {
                fss.mkdir(heicDir);
            }
            
            ByteArrayOutputStream outHeic = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            InputStream inHeic = fss.openInputStream(heicFile);
            Util.copy(inHeic, outHeic);
            byte[] heicData = outHeic.toByteArray();
            
            byte[] jpegData = nativeInterface.heicToJpeg(heicData);
            
            String jpegFile = heicDir + "/" + DeviceUtilities.getUniqueId() + ".jpg";
            OutputStream outJpeg = fss.openOutputStream(jpegFile);
            ByteArrayInputStream inJpeg = new ByteArrayInputStream(jpegData);
            Util.copy(inJpeg, outJpeg);
            
            return jpegFile;
            
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Since the Android counterpart works, I hope that the rest of my custom gallery code is fine and that this out-of-memory issue is inside code I posted here.

I hope you can indicate me a working solution. Thank you

Comment: I think you need to add `[image release]` before the return to free the image you allocated.

Comment: I had already tried, and I tried again now, but it doesn't work. It doesn't work either `return [mediaData autorelease]`. Any other suggestions? Maybe I need a completely different approach?

Comment: We'll need to look into that. It's possible that there's an inherent memory leak here that we didn't notice if the volume was relatively small but one that's noticeable for larger volumes of data

Comment: I'm just started looking into it and I think we do have issues with memory leaks in native interface calls on iOS.   I'll have this fixed soon - won't make the release today, but will for next friday's release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a memory leak in the way that the iOS port invoked native interface methods which received or returned primitive arrays (`byte[]`, `int[]`, etc..).

I have just committed a fix for this (native interface invocations are now wrapped in an autorelease pool) which will be available on the build server next Friday (October 9, 2020).

EDIT: (Friday October 2, 2020)

This fix has been deployed to the build server already so it you should be able to build it again immediately and see if it fixes your issue.